# Javascript load images from a folder and show equal value of wordpress_post_id

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, directory

I have a folder with images in .jpg, named with an id (for ex. "01.jpg" , "02.jpg" ecc) and i must to show only the image that have the same name of my wordpress post ID.
First code's part is uncorrect. Someone can help me?

```
var g = require ('glob') ;
g('*.jpg') function (er, files);
if(count($imagenames)) {
natcasesort($imagenames);
foreach($imagenames as $imagename) {
   if $wordpress_post_id == $imagename;
   echo <img src="<?php echo $imagename ?>">
   else echo 'IMAGE NOT FOUND';
   }
```

Comment: _g('*.jpg') function (er, files);_ is the function (er, files) a new function declaration?

Answer (score 0):

It seems syntax errors in your code. I have made some corrections. Please compare and try.

```
 var g = require ('glob') ;
 g('*.jpg') function (er, files); 
 if(count($imagenames)) {
      natcasesort($imagenames); 
      foreach($imagenames as $imagename) {
             if ($wordpress_post_id == $imagename) {
                 echo "<img src='$imagename'>";
             } else { 
                 echo 'IMAGE NOT FOUND';
             } 
      } 
  }
```